# How to count number of Corners in an image?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to calculate the number of corners in a computer image( a simple image created using tools such as Microsoft Paint).  For example, if I draw a picture of a square, I want the program to return the number of corners, which is 4 in this case.

I am using Open CV 2.4.11 for C++ in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

I've used the Harris Corner detector to display the corners in the image. This is the tutorial I've used for the program : http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html

Also, I would like to know how I can find the end-points of an edge (not the corners)? For example, if the image were to contain line segment the program should return the number of end-points as 2.  What function should I use?

Please resolve this query. I will use this feature in a project.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

P.S: I am a student and a beginner in OpenCV.

Answer (score 4):

If the input is a simple computer-generated image, a viable option is to use thresholding and contour detection.

Once you have extracted the contour (as a vector of points) you can use the `approxPolyDP` function to approximate the detected contour (to a user-defined accuracy). After the approximation the number of points in the output contour is the number of corners (or end-points in case of an open contour).

To summarize, the OpenCV functions you'll need are:
[threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#cv2.threshold),
[findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours)
and [approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=approxpoly#cv2.approxPolyDP).

Answer (score 0):

To count the corners, you can use the code snippet provided in your link where they are drawing circles on the corners (with a few small changes)

```
int thresh = 200;
int corner_count = 0;

for (int j=0; j<dst_norm.rows; j++) { 
  for (int i=0; i<dst_norm.cols; i++) {
    if ((int)dst_norm.at<float>(j,i) > thresh) {
      corner_count++;
    }
  }
}
```